# cant figure out why sidebar wouldn't align with the main content at the top

Tags: html, css

i'm kind of a noob at styling but i'm this close to gouging my eyes out here..
I cant figure out why the sidebar on my page wont align with the main content..i used floats and added a clearfix hack but nothing seems to work. Here is the code:
HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Brereton C of E A Primary School</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    </head>

    <body>
        <div class= "container">            
                <header>
                    <div id="logo">
                        <a href="index.html">
                            <img src="img/logo.png" alt = "Brereton C of E A Primary School">
                        </a>
                    </div>                    
                    <nav>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                            <a href="about.html">About Us</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                            <a href="governors.html">Governors</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                            <a href="pta.html">PTA</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                            <a href="contact.html">Conact Us</a>
                            </li>                        

                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </header>

                <div id="main" class="cf">
                    <h2>Welcome to Brereton C of E (A) Primary School</h2>
                    <h3>
                        When you first visit Brereton School, you sense very quickly that it is a vibrant, happy, multi-cultural school with respect, tolerance and celebration at its core.
                    </h3>
                    <p>
                        Then, when you look at the school’s results, you will see that the friendly, caring atmosphere is accompanied by an ethos of supporting pupils to achieve their full potential and raise standards.
                    </p>                

                </div>
                <div id="downloads" class="cf">
                    <div class="box" id="prospectus">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img src="img/prospectus.png">
                        </a>                    
                    </div>

                    <div class="box" id="newsletters">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img src="img/newsletters.png">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>

            <aside class="cf">
                <ul class="sidebar">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Newsletter</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="">Staff</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="">Learning Platform</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="">NCSL</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="">Ofsted Report</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="">Teachernet</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="./Brereton C of E A Primary School_files/Brereton C of E A Primary School.htm">
                    <div><label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for:</label>
                    <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s">
                    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </aside>
            <footer>
                <h1 class="bottom_logo">
                    <a href="index.html">Brereton C of E A Primary School</a>
                </h1>                
            </footer>
        </div>
    </body>

</html> ​
```

And CSS:

```
/* =====START HACK=====*/


*{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
/**
 * For modern browsers
 * 1. The space content is one way to avoid an Opera bug when the
 *    contenteditable attribute is included anywhere else in the document.
 *    Otherwise it causes space to appear at the top and bottom of elements
 *    that are clearfixed.
 * 2. The use of `table` rather than `block` is only necessary if using
 *    `:before` to contain the top-margins of child elements.
 */
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}

/**
 * For IE 6/7 only
 * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
 */
.cf {
    *zoom: 1;
}
/* =====END HACK=====*/

/* =====GENERAL STYLING=====*/

body{
    background: #fefcea; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #fefcea 0%, #efe9bf 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#fefcea), color-stop(100%,#efe9bf)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #fefcea 0%,#efe9bf 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #fefcea 0%,#efe9bf 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #fefcea 0%,#efe9bf 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #fefcea 0%,#efe9bf 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fefcea', endColorstr='#efe9bf',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    width:960px;
    margin:auto;
}
h2{
    font-family: 'Museo500',"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#553A2A;
}
h3,a,p{
    font-family: arial;
}

h3{
    font-size: 15px;
}

p{
    font-size: 12px;
}

a{
    font-size: 12px;

}

    /* =====END GENERAL STYLING=====*/


    /* HEADER*/

#logo {
    width:113px;
    margin:auto;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

nav{
    background:black;
    color:white;
    height: 30px;
    padding-top: 7px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;

}

    nav a{
        color:white;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    nav a:hover{
        color:#e7e7e7;
    }


    #logo
    nav ul{
        list-style: none;    
    }

    nav li{
        display: inline;
        padding-left: 20px;
    }

    /* END HEADER*/

    /* MAIN*/    

#main{
    width: 60%;
    min-width: 400px;
    float: left;
    padding:10px 0;
    border-radius: 5px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
    border: 1px solid #B8B079;
    margin-left: 15px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

    #main h2{
        padding-bottom: 5px;
    }
    #main h3{
        color:#3A3A3A;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    #main p{
        color:#3A3A3A;
        padding-bottom: 50px;
    }



    #downloads{
        width: 50%;
        margin-left: 12px;
        float: left;
    }
    #prospectus{
        float: left;
        padding-right: 10px;
    }
    #newsletters{
        float: left;
    }

    /* END MAIN*/    

    /* ASIDE*/    

aside{
    float:left;
    width: 30%;

}

    aside ul{
        list-style: none;
    }

    /* END ASIDE*/    
​
```

Please help me out here, I did check the questions section but couldnt find a suitable answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I have fixed the side bar issue take a look at the code on http://jsfiddle.net/Jz4eL/ All I have done is add a HTML section wrapper for your main content and set its size as 10% in the css.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Brereton C of E A Primary School</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    </head>

    <body>
        <div class= "container">            
                <header>
                    <div id="logo">
                        <a href="index.html">
                            <img src="img/logo.png" alt = "Brereton C of E A Primary School">
                        </a>
                    </div>                    
                    <nav>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                            <a href="about.html">About Us</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                            <a href="governors.html">Governors</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                            <a href="pta.html">PTA</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                            <a href="contact.html">Conact Us</a>
                            </li>                        

                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </header>
<section>
                <div id="main" class="cf">
                    <h2>Welcome to Brereton C of E (A) Primary School</h2>
                    <h3>
                        When you first visit Brereton School, you sense very quickly that it is a vibrant, happy, multi-cultural school with respect, tolerance and celebration at its core.
                    </h3>
                    <p>
                        Then, when you look at the school’s results, you will see that the friendly, caring atmosphere is accompanied by an ethos of supporting pupils to achieve their full potential and raise standards.
                    </p>                

                </div>
                <div id="downloads" class="cf">
                    <div class="box" id="prospectus">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img src="img/prospectus.png">
                        </a>                    
                    </div>

                    <div class="box" id="newsletters">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img src="img/newsletters.png">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </section>
            <aside class="cf">
                <ul class="sidebar">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Newsletter</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="">Staff</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="">Learning Platform</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="">NCSL</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="">Ofsted Report</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="">Teachernet</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="./Brereton C of E A Primary School_files/Brereton C of E A Primary School.htm">
                    <div><label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for:</label>
                    <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s">
                    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </aside>
            <footer>
                <h1 class="bottom_logo">
                    <a href="index.html">Brereton C of E A Primary School</a>
                </h1>                
            </footer>
        </div>
    </body>

</html> ​
```

CSS changes

```
  /* MAIN*/    
container {width:100%;}

footer {clear:both;}

section{
    width: 60%;
    min-width: 400px;
    float: left;
    padding:10px 0;
    border-radius: 5px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
    border: 1px solid #B8B079;
    margin-left: 15px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
 ​
```

I have also fixed the footer, so its now at the base of the page.

Comment: Thanks alot Albear, although the footer wasn't at the base when I checked jsfidle but you did sort out my issue with the sidebar. What do you reckon the issue was though? thanks again.

Comment: Don't forget to make the answer as accepted and also vote for anyone who has helped you.. :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want the sidebar on the right side of the page.

Try a "float:right;" on `<aside class="cf">`, which should do what you are looking for - this will float the sidebar to the right side of the page.

Right now, the `<aside>` is floated left, and after `<div id="downloads">` (which is itself floated left). Floating left essentially means: "Pull me out of the document flow, attach me to the left side of my parent container, and make all elements on the page after me flow around my right side".

This causes the `<aside>` to "flow" around the floated left `<div id="downloads">` and align to it - in this case, awkwardly stick to its right side.

Comment: Hi smclark89, I tried that before, didn't work. I've obviously got the concepts of floats wrong, will be digging through a few tutorials further down the line. thanks for your input.